# Is academic collaboration overrated? Should one seek it or avoid it?

Tags: collaboration, india

In our country, the first author gets most of the credit and the other authors practically fall much behind. While, the first author should really get more point as he does maximum work, I find the others contributions are not as minuscule as indicated by the weightage rule. To be clear it is 70 percent of the first author and rest gets 30 percent divided by the number of other authors of the paper.

Comment: Welcome to Academia SE. This could be an interesting question, but it needs a few changes to make it suitable for this site : (1) The body of the question is not clearly linked to the question title, please show the relationship explicitly. (2) There is no 'rule' of the sort that you mention, and the numbers seem baseless. If you have any evidence for these please indicate it, else if it is conjecture, mention that.

Comment: Also, in my experience, the field does play a much more important role in this context than the country does.

Comment: Your last phrase makes no clear sense. Are you talking about some monetary reward? Please rewrite it as it seems central to your question.

Comment: @DSVA Some cultures (countries) have a strong tradition of exchanging gifts and favours between family, friends, colleagues etc. Coauthorship is one such gift. This leads to the inflation and the devaluation of coauthorship. Not sure if that is what OP is referring to though.

Comment: @Asdf but science isn't a national thing any more. At least in the fields I know handling coauthorships, corresponding authors, (shared) first authors and the associated standing with those labels are the same in every country but different in different fields.

Comment: @DSVA I was thinking about China specifically, but I guess other countries could also differ. Science is to some degree affected by local customs. Moreover, national funding agencies play a part in shaping science. From the question it seems like you can quantify a scientist total output by weighting first authored and co-authored differently. I guess the purpose of this is to decide if someone has qualified for a PhD, to make hiring and funding decisions etc. But that is speculation on my part.

Answer (score 2):

In many fields collaboration is not only advisable but necessary because the expertise of a single individual is not enough to complete the work necessary. The days when one scientist can do everything themselves is long gone. People have specific areas of expertise and the work required to become a competent expert in every domain needed for a particular effort is too great.

For instance, I do modeling in a number of materials applications. There is literally no way I could do the experiments necessary to support all of the work in my research, so I need to rely on collaborators who have the necessary experience who can perform and guide the complementary experiments, as well as provide the experimental equipment!

Answer (score 1):

This short question conflates multiple difficult issues:

The first is the value of authorship metrics. As Goodhart's Law notes (paraphrased), when a metric becomes a target, it ceases to be useful. When systems use publication count to determine promotion and pay, people will pad their numbers by trading co-authorships, making second-authorships almost useless as a metric (hence they cease to use it). The publication-count metric also leads to more incremental papers for which the research effort is a proportionately smaller part of the paper, and authorship is proportionately more of the work for each paper. I suspect the rise of developing countries and their reliance on publication count is what has led to the explosion in micro-incremental papers all journals have been inundated with in recent years.

The second issue is that of leadership and the need for a "stuckee" or someone who has to be on the hook to be sure the job gets done, who also has the power to see that it does. Humans are just bad at staying in sync with each other, and I can't imagine much getting finished without a lead, particularly given academics' propensity for piling up multiple "top priorities" and leaving many of them on the back burner for extended periods. And unfortunately, the danger in taking on  that lead role is that you may find yourself doing disproportionate amounts of the work, as everyone else can just punch the clock and do the minimum to not get booted off the paper/project. All you can do is choose your collaborators wisely.

Finally there is the issue of division of labor and specialization. A group of people bringing expertise is different areas can accomplish far more, quicker, and more efficiently, than one person trying to do it all. This is true in research just as it is in industry. There's no question of the potential value collaboration can have.

Answer (score 0):

This might depend somewhat on the field. There was a time when almost all papers in mathematics were by single authors, but no longer. There are some fields such as biology or chemistry where there are papers for which the list of authors is longer than the paper itself.

Generally speaking, though, collaboration is a good thing. Taking the numbers you cite, if there were no collaboration, then the "secondary" authors would get no credit whatever and it would be nearly impossible for anyone to move into the upper ranks of a field as they would likely be less known to peers.

There are brilliant people, of course, who need no help to formulate and develop an idea without help, but they are rare. If you are lucky enough to work in an collaborative environment, a lab or seminar, you swim in a sea of ideas. Some are better and some are not so good, but collaboration also allows the members to develop the ideas in a timely manner and to build upon one another's work.

Many junior researchers feel honored to have their name associated in public with that of a senior well respected person, though that has been occasionally abused. In the normal case, however, it gives the junior person visibility and opportunities that they wouldn't otherwise have.

And of course, in some fields, extremely expensive equipment is required and so almost all work is collaborative (CERN in particle physics).

It isn't widely known, perhaps, but even poets often work collaboratively using a peer review process to improve the work of all members in a Workshop. Authorship is seldom shared here, but the work is collaborative nonetheless. Some very famous poems have been developed in this way.

BTW, not all papers have author lists in order of "contribution" or "status". Some are listed alphabetically, or even randomly. In lab sciences, the grant holder/chief investigator is might be listed first (or last), but this is another example of junior members gaining recognition for their contributions, whether small or large.

In fact, in mathematics we now honor collaboration and co authorship. My [Erdős Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s_number) is 4, for example.

Comment: Just FYI, the "mono" in "monograph" refers to the fact that the work is about one subject, not the number of people. A monograph can have multiple authors.

Comment: In my experience, for papers from a professor's group (although likely field dependent), the _last_ author is the professor (grant holder) and the first author is the grad student who contributed the most. Your mileage may vary...

Comment: @JonCuster. Yes, certainly for work based on dissertations it should be done that way. I edited to include your note. Thanks.